# tfs2012: Tree of Work Items with type of tree Successor/Predecessor

Tags: tfs, alm

I need to build query, that return result with network topology with more than 2 level in depth. For example, i wont to get next result:

[image]

but if i build "Work Items and Direct Links" query i get only 1 level depth, and if i build "Tree of Work Items" i can select onl Parent/Child type of tree and can't add my custom Successor/Predecessor type of tree.

So my direct question: may i get more then one level depth in Work Items and Direct Links Query, or change type of tree in "Tree of Work Items" Query? Or i can get that result only by integrating TFS with Project Server like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_planningyourprojects_topic4.aspx)?

Comment: What type of link did you create? (Topology property on the link type)

Comment: @Betty, i want do display items with Network topology. Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I think it only supports Tree as it prevents cycles being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you are talking about and it depends if you want to create reporting or if you are talking about a work breakdown structure.

If you require a work breakdown structure I would recommend changing your process so that you do not, or processing that purely at the PMO level. Enshrining dependencies in a tool at anything lower than the Portfolio suggests to me that you may be creating solutions to effects rather than getting to the route cause of a particulate dysfunction that is enshrined in your culture.[preachMode=false] However...

**#1 - Reporting**

You can create a reporting services report that presents data from both the Data Warehouse and the Cube to create the desired view.

- [Create and Manage Reporting Services Reports for Visual Studio ALM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921483.aspx)

This will give you a read-only view of data and will lead to the least invasive dysfunctions.

**#2 - MS Project**

You can use MS Project to load both the Parent/Child & Network items and maintain the Gant Chart with dependencies that are stored in TFS.

- I could not find a good link but there is documentation on MSDN

This will give you an interactive view of the data in the operational store, but will lead to the most invasive dysfunctions.

**#3 - Project Server**

If you are implementing something more like the [Scaled Agile Framework](http://scaledagileframework.com/) then you may want to take advantage of the Earned Value management of Project Server integration as well as some of the Portfolio Management features.

- [Enable Data Flow Between Team Foundation Server and Microsoft Project Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg455680.aspx)

I hope that you can find something to suit and you get a chance to explore the ramification of your current process on the ability of your teams and organisation to achieve any sort of agility in [the new normal of the modern application lifecycle](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/the-new-normal-of-the-modern-application-lifecycle/).